# print values from list of dict in a unique way

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dict as below

```
x = [
    {'local': 'a', 'local_int' : 'b', 'remote': 'c', 'remote_int': 'd'},
    {'local': 'c', 'local_int' : 'd', 'remote': 'a', 'remote_int': 'b'},
    {'local': 'g', 'local_int' : 'h', 'remote': 'e', 'remote_int': 'f'},
    {'local': 'e', 'local_int' : 'f', 'remote': 'g', 'remote_int': 'h'}
]
```

As you can see above technically ( x[0] and x[1] ) and ( x[2] and x[3] ) are same connections meaning ab connects to cd in x[0] and x[1]. So I only want to print x[0] and x[3] and ignore x[1] and x[2] when I do the for loop on x.

In the o/p I should only have

```
{'local': 'a', 'local_int' : 'b', 'remote': 'c', 'remote_int': 'd'}
{'local': 'e', 'local_int' : 'f', 'remote': 'g', 'remote_int': 'h'}
```

Been trying different methods but haven't succeeded so far. Any help is much appreciated.

I tried to check condition where if x['local'] matches x['remote'] pass but then it won't print anything because it always matches the condition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What code did you use that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
visited_connections = set()
for d in x:
    if d["local"] + d["local_int"] in visited_connections:
        continue
    print(d)
    visited_connections.add(d["local"] + d["local_int"])
    visited_connections.add(d["remote"] + d["remote_int"])
```

This code prints the dictionary only if the connection for the local server has not been printed already.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much